# No such file or directory error using downloadTask in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, watchos-3

I'm trying to fetch the contents of an URL using the `downloadTask` background function  on swift 3. Using `dataTask`, things work as they should. However, when using the `downloadTask` function, my `didCompleteWithError` delegate is called. When I check at the response sent by the server, I see that the status code is 200.

Here's the error message:

> Optional(Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat=59.000;lon=10.000, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat=59.000;lon=10.000})

My code is:

```
let urlo = URL(string: "https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat=59.000;lon=10.000")
var request = URLRequest(url: urlo!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
let backgroundConfigObject = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "MYUPDATING")
let backgroundSession = URLSession(configuration: backgroundConfigObject, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
let taskTemps = backgroundSession.downloadTask(with: request)
taskTemps.resume()
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: This was a bug. Apparently it is fixed in XCode 8.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug on XCode. Apparently it got fixed in XCode 8.3. Things work as they should now.

Comment: To be honest, it seems the bug is back... :S